# How to compare types

Tags: c#, .net

Quick question: how to compare a Type type (pun not intended) with another type in C#?
I mean, I've a `Type typeField` and I want to know if it is `System.String`, `System.DateTime`, etc., but `typeField.Equals(System.String)` doesn't work.

Any clue?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Try the following

```
typeField == typeof(string)
typeField == typeof(DateTime)
```

The `typeof` operator in C# will give you a `Type` object for the named type.  `Type` instances are comparable with the `==` operator so this is a good method for comparing them.

Note: If I remember correctly, there are some cases where this breaks down when the types involved are COM interfaces which are embedded into assemblies (via NoPIA).  Doesn't sound like this is the case here.

Comment: I think this will work, if the two objects you're comparing are value types. If they're object types I don't believe this will work. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @Rod From what I can tell after some tampering your assumption is right. A very dirty workaround is to compare the `ToString()` result of each parameter.

Answer (score 89):

You can use for it the `is` [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). You can then check if object is specific type by writing:

```
if (myObject is string)
{
  DoSomething()
}
```

Comment: Is it better to us "is" or "typeof"?

Comment: @BrentWaggoner This answer may be super late. The `is` keyword and `typeof` seems to behave differently, for example, I have a `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` that derived from the `BaseClass`. If I declare a variable called `var testClass = new DerivedClass();`, then I compare like `if (testClass is BaseClass)` the result will be `true`, but if I compare like `if (testClass.GetType() == typeof(BaseClass))` the result will be `false`. In conclusion, use `typeof` if you need to explicitly compare a derived class

Comment: summary of @BrentWaggoner 's comment : "typeof" checks the EXACT type, where as "is" checks the type... PLUS its ancestors.

Answer (score 34):

You can compare for exactly the same type using:

```
class A {
}
var a = new A();
var typeOfa = a.GetType();
if (typeOfa == typeof(A)) {
}
```

typeof returns the Type object from a given class.

But if you have a type B, that inherits from A, then this comparison is false. And you are looking for [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx).

```
class B : A {
}
var b = new B();
var typeOfb = b.GetType();

if (typeOfb == typeof(A)) { // false
}

if (typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(typeOfb)) { // true
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If your instance is a `Type`:

```
Type typeFiled;
if (typeField == typeof(string))
{ 
    ... 
}
```

but if your instance is an `object` and not a `Type` use the `as` operator:

```
object value;
string text = value as string;
if (text != null)
{
    // value is a string and you can do your work here
}
```

this has the advantage to convert `value` only once into the specified type.

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx

```
Console.WriteLine("typeField is a {0}", typeField.GetType());
```

which would give you something like

```
typeField is a String

typeField is a DateTime
```

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(v=vs.71).aspx