# Brief understanding of interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, interface

I have an interface which says setMaster();
and 2 classes from which i`m setting the respective master pages based on the scenario.

I need to understand what the following code means:

```
 Control pageControl = LoadControl(pageControlPath);
 if (pageControl is IVariableMasterPageControl)
 {
     ((IVariableMasterPageControl)pageControl).setMaster();
 }
```

My Code:

Interface:

```
interface IVariableMasterPageControl
{
    void setMaster();
}
```

Classes:

```
public class VariableMasterControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IVariableMasterPageControl
{
    public void setMaster()
    {
        this.Page.MasterPageFile = ("~/ui/" + SiteConfiguration.UIID + "/MasterPageOne.Master");
    }
}
```

Comment: when i debug this, i`m stuck on the line which says,
 if (pageControl is IVariableMasterPageControl)
what does "is" here pointing to ? it is pointing to the class or the interface?

Comment: where do you feel you're not understanding the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are showing loads a UserControl dynamically. The call to `LoadControl` method returns an instance of type `Control`. This can be any control that might or might not implement the interface `IVariableMasterPageControl`. So, if you want to call the `setMaster` method, you need to check whether the control implements the interface before accessing the control over the interface. This is what the `if` statement is doing.

The `is` Statement checks whether an [object is compatible with a given type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) so that it can be cast to that type. In your case, the line

```
if (pageControl is IVariableMasterPageControl)
```

checks whether `pageControl` implements `IVariableMasterPageControl` so that it can cast it safely in the next line.

As you need the reference to the interface afterwards, an alternative would be to use the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator:

```
Control pageControl = LoadControl(pageControlPath);
var varMasterPageCtrl = pageControl as IVariableMasterPageControl;
if (varMasterPageCtrl != null)
    varMasterPageCtrl.setMaster();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are doing custom ASCX controls, some of which implement the interface IVariableMasterPageControl. The code which you have trouble understanding is checking, if the control in question implements the interface or not. If it does, it accesses the method setMaster() of the control - which obviously had to be implemented.

The code

```
if (pageControl is IVariableMasterPageControl)
```

Is the part where the check is done to see if the control actually implements the interface or not. This can also be done in the following manner;

```
if (pageControl.GetType() == typeof(IVariableMasterPageControl))
```

Take a look at this link: [How to compare types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482844/how-to-compare-types). May help you out comparing types and understanding more in depth the concept.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, the `is` keyword basically says: "if this instance of `PageControl` implements the interface `IVariableMasterPageControl`, then call the interface's `SetMaster()` method for that `PageControl`."

The check using the `is` keyword makes sure, that your object actually *has* a method `SetMaster()` to call. You could iterate through a bunch of `PageControl` objects, but there's no guarantee that all of them would implement the interface. Calling a non-existent method without a check would certainly either cause an `Exception` or could even call the wrong code (if, say, one of the `PageControl` objects implements *an other* interface that just happens to also define a method `SetMaster()`).